# Is it possible we can use htaccess File in Nginx (I Did not able to use)

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I want to Use htaccess File Nginx

```
https://apkkingo.com/pixomatic-mod-apk/
```

```
https://apkkingo.com/pixomatic-mod-apk/
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use `.htaccess` files with the Nginx webserver. Nginx does not support per-directory config files in the public-HTML space. You need to edit the main server config.

`.htaccess` files are an Apache (per-directory) config file. LiteSpeed (a "drop-in" replacement for Apache) also supports `.htaccess` files.

IIS does not support `.htaccess` natively either, but there is a paid plugin (called [Helicon Ape](https://www.helicontech.com/ape/)) that also gives `.htaccess` like ability (with some differences).